# NgRX: "No provider for Store!" after upgrading from14 to 15

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store

After upgrading, I started getting the `No provider for Store!` error during the bootup of my application.

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ... ],
  imports: [
    ...

    StoreModule.forRoot({
      offer: offerReducer,
      ui: offerUIReducer,
    }),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([OfferEffects]),
  ],
  providers: [ ... ],
})
export class OfferModule { }
```

The full stack trace

```
apps_rita_src_app_offer_offer_module_ts.js:2 Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: NullInjectorError: No provider for Store!
Error: NullInjectorError: No provider for Store!
    at NullInjector.get (core.mjs:7599:27) [angular]
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:8020:33) [angular]
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:8020:33) [angular]
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:8020:33) [angular]
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:634:33) [angular]
    at Module.ɵɵinject (core.mjs:638:60) [angular]
    at Object.EffectsRunner_Factory [as factory] (ngrx-effects.mjs:147:112) [angular]
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.mjs:8121:35) [angular]
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:8009:33) [angular]
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:8020:33) [angular]
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:634:33) [angular]
    at Module.ɵɵinject (core.mjs:638:60) [angular]
    at Object.EffectsRootModule_Factory [as useFactory] (ngrx-effects.mjs:147:112) [angular]
    at Object.factory (core.mjs:8208:38) [angular]
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1214:31) [angular]
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1168:17) [angular]
    at :4200/polyfills.js:8513:9 [angular]
    at :4200/vendor.js:91039:49 [angular]
    at AsyncStackTaggingZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:23999:36) [angular]
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:24300:33) [angular]
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:588:35) [<root>]
```

Where the `ngrx-effects.mjs:147:112` is:

```js
/** @nocollapse */ Actions.ɵfac = i0.ɵɵngDeclareFactory({ minVersion: "12.0.0", version: "15.0.0", ngImport: i0, type: Actions, deps: [{ token: ScannedActionsSubject }], target: i0.ɵɵFactoryTarget.Injectable });
/** @nocollapse */ Actions.ɵprov = i0.ɵɵngDeclareInjectable({ minVersion: "12.0.0", version: "15.0.0", ngImport: i0, type: Actions, providedIn: 'root' });
i0.ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata({ minVersion: "12.0.0", version: "15.0.0", ngImport: i0, type: Actions, decorators: [{
  type: Injectable,
  args: [{ providedIn: 'root' }]
}], ctorParameters: function () { return [{ type: i1.Observable, decorators: [{
  type: Inject,
  args: [ScannedActionsSubject]
}] }]; } });
```

PS: Moving the store to the root module did not help either...

Comment: did you also upgrade `ngrx` to v15 or latest as well?

Comment: @Andres2142 I did. To the version 15.1.0

Comment: Is `OfferModule` the only place you use the Store?

Comment: @WillAlexander Yes, I have 2 routes and each has its own module. A lot inside the `OfferModule` use the Store, but nothing from the other route.

Comment: Have you tried calling `StoreModule.forRoot` in your root module, and then calling `StoreModule.forFeature` in OfferModule? You'd have to do the same with `EffectsModule`. In the `forRoot` calls, you pass an empty object/empty array. That way you know for sure the Store is initialised at startup.

Comment: @WillAlexander It did work, but my app broke because the store was undefined... do not know why...

Comment: Is OfferModule eager loaded or lazy loaded?

Comment: @WillAlexander Lazy loaded